# Using QGIS to create a GeoTIFF raster of Google Earth import

Tags: qgis, raster, geotiff-tiff, google-earth

I've managed to link QGIS3 to Google Earth via XYZ tiles.  I would like to convert the Google Earth map shown to a GeoTIFF raster (to save on memory?).  I try and export the Google Earth layer to a GeoTIFF raster and notice a the bottom of the screen I have to choose extent - assume I click mapview extent, because the original Google Earth files must be large? And then I need to select the resolution?  This is the bit where I am struggling, because on the layout composer canvas I want to produce a map at A0 size with a scale of 1:5000, and if this works, at 1:1250.  A previous post I've found noted that the resolution units are metres per pixel - so how do I choose an appropriate resolution, noting the printing specifications of the map to be produced?  Also a previous post queried whether this method of exporting Google Earth data is actually allowed?

Comment: You can find some information about terms of service for google map layers here: https://www.google.at/permissions/geoguidelines/attr-guide.html. That might not take you to *exactly* the right section of guidelines, so be sure to follow any relevant links.

Comment: It might depend on whether and how you're publishing and distributing your maps.

Answer (score 1):

The image resolution of your exported geotiff won't affect the scale of the map you produce with it. When you produce a map in the print composer, QGIS will automatically zoom in or out on the image to the same scale as the map (that's the point of making it a georeferenced image rather than just a picture).

The resolution you choose just has to do with how pixelated or clear the image looks. A lower resolution will be more pixelated. A higher resolution will be more clear, but it will be a larger file size.

If you want to export exactly the area you currently see on your screen, choose the "map canvas extent" export option. [image]

Otherwise, choose the option to "draw on canvas," which allows you to directly select a rectangular area on your map canvas. [image]

The `Save map as image` dialogue provides a very confusing combination of settings for scale, resolution (in dpi/dots per inch) and output width/height (in pixels). Frankly, these seem like contradictory options. The [User Manual](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/project_files.html#sec-output) is not especially helpful here. I think your best bet to find the right settings will be by trial and error.